# SVG drop shadow hexagon

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created a svg hexagon but want to put drop-shadow on the outermost.
But now the shadow I put on is right in the picture.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96" height="110" viewbox="0 0 95.26279441628824 110" style=" filter:drop-shadow(rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.25) 0px 20px 10px)">
  <defs>
    <pattern
      id="img1"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      width="96"
      height="110"
    >
      <image
        href="https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/52-526033_unknown-person-icon-png-transparent-png.png"
        x="0"
        y="27.5"
        width="96"
        height="55"
      />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path
    fill="url(#img1)"
    stroke="#A4B3C6"
    d="M45.033320996790806 1.4999999999999998Q47.63139720814412 0 50.22947341949744 1.5L92.66471820493493 26Q95.26279441628824 27.5 95.26279441628824 30.5L95.26279441628824 79.5Q95.26279441628824 82.5 92.66471820493493 84L50.22947341949744 108.5Q47.63139720814412 110 45.033320996790806 108.5L2.598076211353316 84Q0 82.5 0 79.5L0 30.5Q0 27.5 2.598076211353316 26Z"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Take the drop shadow off the SVG element. Don't use a pattern. Fill the hexagon path with white, and put the dropshadow on the path element. Then just position the image element on top of the hexagon.